# Inserting multiple var values into same mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my first 'built from the ground up' PHP/MySQL project. I've built a very simple HTML form with the same row repeated multiple times:

```
<h2 style="margin-top:0">Current Projects</h2>      
    Project: <input name="project1" type="text"  size="40" value="1" /> 
    Status: <input name="status1" type="text" size="40" value="1" /> 
    Estimated Completion: <input name="estCompletion1" type="text" size="12" value="1" /><br /> 

    Project: <input name="project2" type="text" size="40" value="2" /> 
    Status: <input name="status2" type="text" size="40" value="2" /> 
    Estimated Completion: <input name="estCompletion2" type="text" size="12" value="2" /><br />

    Project: <input name="project3" type="text" size="40" value="3" /> 
    Status: <input name="status3" type="text" size="40" value="3" /> 
    Estimated Completion: <input name="estCompletion3" type="text" size="12" value="3" /><br />
```

I'm trying to write all of these to the same database table at the same time, but on different rows.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO current_project (date, est_completion, project_name, status)
VALUES  (NOW(), '$estCompletion1', '$project1', '$status1'),
        (NOW(), '$estCompletion2', '$project2', '$status2'),
        (NOW(), '$estCompletion3', '$project3', '$status3')";
```

The problem with doing it like this is that it inserts the data from the variable, even if it's null. So if the user only enters data in the first row of fields (project1, status1, etc.) the other 2 insert an empty row.

Is there a way, maybe using 'if isset()', so that I don't have any blank fields in my database?

Comment: have you tried building your sql query dynamically - checking values before concatenating the string onto the rest? Edited to say - yes, with if isset() I would check every entry before adding a line to the sql query

Comment: Seems easier to insert one row at a time so you don't have to concern yourself with the other rows if they are not filled out. 
Somebody could fill in row 1 and 3 and leave row 2 blank also to cause an issue.

Comment: r lo - I tried doing each one individually, but it only writes the last one to the database, ignoring the previous ones.

Comment: wribit - Can you give me an example of how this would be written?

Answer (score 0):

Build SQL dynamically.

Something like this:

```
$inserts = Array();
for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++) {
    if (!$_POST["project".$i] && !$_POST["status".$i] && !$_POST["estCompletion".$i]) continue;
    $inserts[] = "(NOW(), '".$_POST["estCompletion".$i]."', '".$_POST["project".$i]."', '".$_POST["status".$i]."')";
}
if (Count($inserts)>0) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO current_project (date, est_completion, project_name, status) 
    VALUES (" . implode("), (", $inserts) . ")";
}
```

At this point $sql should have full SQL query only with those rows where all three fields were submitted.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. I don't get a PHP error, but nothing posts to the database and it doesn't go to thankyou.php.

Comment: Out put the `$sql` and check how many values you trying to insert. And what the values are. May be you need to `addslashes()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the value of posted variable is null, always use **empty()** method.

For more information: Visit [php.net](https://www.php.net/empty)

```
 for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++) {
        $estCompletion= $_POST["estCompletion".$i];
        $project= $_POST["project".$i];
        $status= $_POST["status".$i];
        
        if (!empty($estCompletion) && !empty($project) && !empty($status))
        {       
            $sql = "INSERT INTO current_project (date, est_completion, project_name, status) VALUES  (NOW(), '".$estCompletion."', '".$project."', '".$status."')";
        }

    unset($estCompletion, $project, $status);  
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Pankaj! I get what you're doing here, and I like it! The only problem is that it still just inserts the last row into the database, instead of all 3 rows (if they're not empty, or course). Also I got an error because the code is missing a closing curly brace.

Comment: @danzo As per your suggestion, I redacted the script.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. The issue now is that the script only inserts the last row. It should be writing 3 rows (if all three are not empty) If all three rows are filled in, it only inserts the last one. How do we get it to loop through the script to insert each row?